# Websphere MQ in C#: Where in the code to set SSL Keystore Password?

Tags: c#, ssl, ibm-mq

I have an MQ application that I need to use SSL connections with.  I have been given a keystore to use and a password to use it, but what I am unsure of is where I need to go to set the value of the keystore password?

There are a few places in the MQ DLL's that I can see a password setting, but I don't want to set it in the wrong place.  All of the other SSL stuff has been under the MQENVIRONMENT and there is a password there, but I can't seem to find anything that confirms this as the correct place.

What is the value I need to set for my SSL keystore's password?

(NOTE: I am writing this in C# using MQ version 7.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .Net classes do not use a Java keystore, but rather they use the WMQ kdb format keystore.  This file format includes a "Stash file" which contains an obfuscated password.  Point your program to the kdb in the environment variables as discussed [on this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10620_.htm) of the docs.  The kdb is actually several files with the same prefix and different suffixes.  What you see in the example is that the variable includes the path and the kdb prefix but no suffix.

I'm guessing the next question is "how do I get my jks into this kdb format?"  To do this you must have GSKit installed.  It is bundled with both WMQ Client and WMQ Server but depending on the version installed, the path differs slightly.  Look under `C:\Program Files\IBM\gsk7` for starters.  There are several different user interfaces but the one you want is the compiled gsk7cmd.

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\gsk7\bin>gsk7cmd.exe -keydb -convert

A required value for the command was not specified:  
-db                                 Required  

-Correct command usage-  
-db                                 Required  
-pw                                 Optional  
-target                             Optional  
-new_pw                             Optional  
-old_format or -type                Optional  
-new_format                         Required  <cms | jceks | jks | kdb | p12 | pkcs12>  
-expire                             Optional  <0 - 7300>  
-stash                              Optional`
```

When converting from jks to kdb, be sure to specify the -stash option so that the program can find the password.

Comment: I was supplied with 4 key files (a crt, kdb, rdb, and sth).  I was just told that needed to specify a password to use them.

Comment: You were told wrong.  :-)  The .sth file contains the password.  When I saw that you were told to use a password, I assumed they gave you a jks.  Just put all the files in the same directory and point the environment variable to them as described in the link to the docs above.  The env var to set is `MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository`.

Comment: So when I get an error like: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable. 

It means they gave me a crappy stash file?

Comment: Yes.  You can create a new stash file if you know the password.  The gsk7cmd can do that.  Or else tell whoever gave you the files to fix it and give you a good file.  You can rename the stash file and specify the password on the gsk7cmd command line to verify whether the password they gave you works on the kdb file they supplied.

Comment: `gsk7cmd -keydb -db "C:\path\kdbname" -pw password -type kdb -stashpw` will create the stash file with the supplied password.

Comment: By the way, if you are still struggling with this, you might have missed a subtle point mentioned above and in the docs - don't include the file suffix in the name.  For example, use "C:\path\kdbname" instead of "C:\path\kdbname.kdb".  If you use the latter format, the classes construct a name for the stash file that looks like "C:\path\kdbname.kdb.sth" which is reported as "absent or unusable".